# Harmonizer Effect

Tags: audio

I know that to build Harmonizer I need pitch shift the signal in differents ways, my question is how know for what scale/factor/notes/frequency I need pitch shift to create harmony?

For example if i press a middle C piano key how create two or three harmonization for this key ?

I believe to create 3 harmonizer the output should be similar to:

```
MixHarmony = OriginalSound + Pitch_shifted_to_X + Pitch_shifted_to_Y
```

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://music.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: This question appears to be about sonic properties of audio effects rather than about the signal processing involved.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have use some basic music theory to know "how to harmonize middle-C". For example, if you play a G4 and E4, you will be making a harmony with a basic 3-note chord (C-E-G). However, this is only the simplest option and there are many combinations of notes in the theory of Harmony.

To get from notes that create the harmony (C-E-G) to frequencies (to pitch-shift the signal), you need to use a pitch standard like [A440](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A440_%28pitch_standard%29) and a scale (from which to select notes).

Perhaps to start, it would be better to use the standard [Piano key frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies), to quickly get the required frequencies (note use of A440)

Comment: user27 needs to understand a little about the diatonic scale and these different scales like Ionian (major), Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, Mixolydian, Aeolian (minor), and Locrian.  you know that "whole, whole, half, whole, whole, whole, half" thing.  from that you can construct a pitch-in to pitch-out mapping function (you need a pitch detector, but a good harmonizer has such a thing) and from that a pitch-in to shift amount mapping.